# Accepted an answer but didn't receive the two reputation award

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

I have accepted an answer to my question, but my reputations didn't increase by 2. Why did that happen?

I haven't reached the daily reputation limit; I think.

Comment: The +2 from acceptance isn't affected by the daily reputation limit anyway. If you earn 200 in a day and then accept an answer, you'll earn 202.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You received **2** reputation points by accepting the answer to your [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/527480/why-are-host-and-hostile-lookalike-while-they-are-of-different-meanings) but someone downvoted your post and you got **-2** so it didn't show up (i.e. +2 -2 = 0).

Your initial reputation was 101 then you received +10 from an upvote and your reputation became 111 then you accepted the answer and got +2 from that and then someone downvoted your post (-2) so the total reputation became 111.

Here's a screenshot of the votes on your question:
[image: Votes on OP's question]